# How to assign value of the array position in Android Java?

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist, wifimanager

I know how to get value of a position of the array and Compare the values of the array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < listadosWifi.size(); i++) {
            /* pega o SSID e o BSSID */
            providerName = "\n"+(listadosWifi.get(i).SSID).toString()+ "\n"+(listadosWifi.get(i).level);
            listViwProvider = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view_wifi);
            listaFornecedores.add(providerName);
            t1.speak("Redes Disponíveis: " + providerName, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null, null);
            t1.setPitch(1);

                if (listadosWifi.get(i).level < -10 && listadosWifi.get(i).level > -50 ) {
                    t1.speak("Você está próximo de: " + providerName, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);
                    t1.setPitch(1);
                    if(listadosWifi.get(i).level < -50){
                        t1.speak("Você está próximo de: " + providerName, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);
                        t1.setPitch(1);
                    }
              }             
 }
```

finally how can i assign the value of one array position to the one on another array in java.

I DO NOT want to copy the values from one array to another.
I need to match the values of an array to another.

For Exemple: the WiFi name and it's signal
WifiName is one array and WiFiSignal is in another array.

Comment: Don't do that.  Instead create your own class that holds all the associated data, and create an array of that class.

Comment: thanks you! I'll try to do it... but how can i use thread together to update the datas?